# Different CSS transition-delays for hover and mouseout?

Tags: css, transition, css-transitions

Is it possible to use CSS3 transitions with a different delay switching between "states"? For example, I'm trying to make an element immediately higher upon hover then on 'mouseout' to wait a second before sliding back to the element's initial height.

**Demo page:** [jsfiddle.net/RTj9K](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/RTj9K/) (hover black box in top-right corner)

**CSS:** `#bar { transition:.4s ease-out 0, 1s; }`

I thought the timings on the end related to delay but it doesn't seem to be working the way I'd imagined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607330/css-display-none-and-opacity-animation-with-keyframes-not-working

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you want different CSS transition delays on `hover` and `mouseout`, you have to set them using the relevant selectors. In the example below, when an element is hovered, the initial delay on hover is `0` but on `mouseout` the transition is delayed by `1s`.

```css
/* These transition properties apply on "mouseout" */
#bar { transition:height .5s ease-out 1s; } 

/* These transition properties apply on hover */
#bar:hover { transition:height .5s ease-out 0s; }
```

You can find the full CSS in my question's updated demo below. I've used the shorthand `transition` property, the order of the values are:

```
transition:<property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
```

### Answer Demo: http://jsbin.com/lecuna/edit?html,css,output

Comment: the problem I see with this is when you move the mouse away quickly it will get stuck in the middle until your delay is gone..

Comment: @apieceofbart you can work around that by conditionally applying another class that doesn't set a transition-delay in the ontransitionend listener

Comment: @OlegVaskevich Actually I had a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594931/reversible-transition-with-delay
There was a beautiful answer given :)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simplified [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/RXG3w/). Basically you need the [`transition-delay`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-delay) property:

```css
#transform {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:black;
    transition: .4s ease-out; 
    transition-delay: 2s;
    /*or shorthand: transition: .4s ease-out 2s;*/
}

#transform:hover {
    transition: .4s ease-out; 
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Let's say there are two elements. On hover, i want the first one to appear before the second one; then when the mouse leave, i want the second one to disappear first, then the first one to disappear. Can' really get it… neither if it could be working

Comment: @Ben Post a question and I'll take a look at it. Also show some html. I think you should have different animations on each element. In the hover anim A's delay should be less than B's delay. On non hover animation it should be reversed. PS: I'm no expert with these... I just fiddled until it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

```css
/* These transition properties apply on "mouseout" */
#bar { transition:height .5s ease-out 1s; } 

/* These transition properties apply on hover */
#bar:hover { transition:height .5s ease-out 0; }
```

Just to say that this won't work if you do not enter 's' (seconds) symbol, so:

```css
/* These transition properties apply on "mouseout" */
#bar { transition:height .5s ease-out 1s; } 

/* These transition properties apply on hover */
#bar:hover { transition:height .5s ease-out 0s; }   /* note "0s" */
```

Comment: the note about adding the "s" to the `0` is super important. I was just bitten by it but figured it out. +1