# CSS display none and opacity animation with keyframes not working

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a very basic piece of HTML with the objective of animating from `display: none;` to `display: block` with opacity changing from 0 to 1.

I'm using Chrome browser, which uses the `-webkit` prefixes as preference and did a `-webkit-keyframes` transition set to make the animation possible. However, it does not work and just changes the `display` without fading.

I have a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5g4yLcym/).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myDiv
                {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
                padding: 5px;
                color: #600;
                background-color: #CEC;
                -webkit-transition: 350ms display-none-transition;
                }

            #parent:hover>#myDiv
                {
                opacity: 1;
                display: block;
                }

            #parent
                {
                background-color: #000;
                color: #FFF;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                padding: 5px;
                }

            @-webkit-keyframes display-none-transition
                {
                0% {
                    display: none; 
                    opacity: 0;
                    }

                1% 
                    {
                    display: block; 
                    opacity: 0;
                    }

                100% 
                    {
                    display: block; 
                    opacity: 1;
                    }
                }
        </style>
        <body>
            <div id="parent">
                Hover on me...
                <div id="myDiv">
                    Hello!
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using `@keyframes` you should use `-webkit-animation` instead of `-webkit-transition`. Here is the doc for `@keyframes` animation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations.

See code snippet below:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.myDiv {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #600;
  background-color: #cec;
}
.parent:hover .myDiv {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  /* "both" tells the browser to use the above opacity
  at the end of the animation (best practice) */
  -webkit-animation: display-none-transition 1s both;
  animation: display-none-transition 1s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes display-none-transition {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes display-none-transition {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Hover on me...
  <div class="myDiv">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

---

### 2016 UPDATED ANSWER

To reflect today's best practices, I would use a transition instead of an animation. Here is the updated code:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.myDiv {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #600;
  background-color: #cec;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.parent:hover .myDiv {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Hover on me...
  <div class="myDiv">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The display property isn't animatable. You can remove it from the keyframe animation with the same result.

Comment: this saved my day... I was using transition and @keyframes, and that was my problem... thank you!

Answer (score 40):

The `display` doesn't work with CSS transition or animation.

Use `opacity`, `visibility` or `z-index`. You can combine all them.

Try to use `visibility: visible` in place `display: block` and `visibility: hidden` in place `display: none`.

And finally, combine `z-index: -1` and `z-index: 100` for example.

Good work ;)

Comment: Don't forget that `z-index` only applies to positioned elements; use `position:relative` if you need it.

Answer (score 16):

You can not animate `display` property. You can try with `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visible`

Comment: No you can do it with display property:
by switshing between `display:none;` and `display:block;` .

Comment: No you can't , the display property is not animatable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Theorically it's not desgned to do it but you can do it, see [the answer in this exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript).

Answer (score 6):

Just use `position: fixed` and drop the `z-index: -5` at the end of the `@keyframe` animation (you can do any negative index....

CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { opacity: 1

  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### It's been tricky, it's been nasty, but here it is...

[image]

- FadeOut (opacity) first
- then truly hide (meaning: not covering up or catching any clicks, getting `height: 0`,...)

  - `display: <whatever>` is indeed no option.
  - But animating `scaleY` is. Or `translate` to far-far-away or the old classic: animating `max-height` (from a specific high px value) down to 0px…

For an earlier version of this snippet with some more general info on „back and forth animation on class toggle“ (and preventing that animation upon initial page load [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819781/444255).

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.target')

function toggleTarget() {
  div.classList.add('active');
  div.classList.toggle('play');
}
```

```css
/* REF https://stackoverflow.com/a/49575979 */
/* REF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607330/css-display-none-and-opacity-animation-with-keyframes-not-working/64857102#64857102 */
body, html { /* eye candy */
  background: #444; display: flex; min-height: 100vh; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
}
button { font-size: 4em; border-radius: 20px; margin-left: 60px;}

div { /* eye candy */
  width: 200px; height: 100px; border-radius: 20px;
  background: green; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 2em; color: white; text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  
}

/* using this extra .active class prevents that there is an animation already on loading */
.active {
  animation: fadeAndHideBack 1s linear forwards;
}

.play {  
  opacity: 0;
  /* learning curve: setting background "awaits" animation finish,
     setting scale prematurely jumps to it, then doing animation from there */

  animation: fadeAndHide 1s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes fadeAndHide {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  99.9% { opacity: 0; max-height: 100px; }
  100% { opacity: 0; max-height: 0; }
}

@keyframes fadeAndHideBack {
  0% { opacity: 0; max-height: 0; }
  0.1% { opacity: 0; max-height: 100px; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="target"></div>
<button onclick="toggleTarget()">
  Toggle
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to change both the display properties and animation. You can't put display in `@keyframes`.

Start with the element `display:none`. Then simultaneously add `display:block` and `animation:*` classes.

[Here's a working example](http://codepen.io/swieder/pen/RNqVqY) with animation in/out.

Answer (score 1):

add this css ;

```
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

this work for me..

Answer (score 0):

How about this example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/hq6n6zcx/) 
The issue was needing to use an animation rather than transition with keyframes

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0.25;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#myDiv {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #600;
    background-color: #CEC;
}
#parent {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#parent:hover #myDiv {
    -webkit-animation: fadeAnimation 6s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the *display* property. You can animate the *visibility* property. But *visibility* is not the same as *display*, as it will not remove the div element completely from the DOM (the property, *visibility:collapse*, can remove an element from the DOM, if the element is a table. This is an exception). You can instead animate CSS properties *height* and *width*. For instance, the below code will animate the square-block out.

```js
function myAnimation(){
 var square= document.getElementById('square');
  if(square.getAttribute("class")==='square'){
    square.classList.add('animation');
  }else{
    square.classList.remove('animation');
  }
}
```

```css
.square {
    background-color:blue;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.square.animation {
    transform: translate(-260px, -260px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="square" id="square"></div>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="myAnimation()">Animate</button> 
 </body>
</html>
```

FYI, I have used CSS transitions to animate the div. Hope this was useful.