# delayed button animation CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the "enter" button to display after the typing animation has been completed. 
If I set display: none before the animation, it won't display even after the animation completes. I think the problem lies in the "@keyframe clickit" but I can't figure out what it is.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko);
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #3c3f41;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.exec h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:
        typing 1s steps(20, end),
        cursor 0.5s step-end infinite;
    /*animation-delay: 5s;*/
}
@keyframes typing {
    from{ width: 0 }
    to{ width: 100% }
}
@keyframes cursor{
    from, to {
        border-color: transparent;}
    50% {
        border-color: orange;
    }
}
.enter{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 15px;
    min-width: 70px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    /*display: none;*/
    animation-name: clickit;
    animation-delay: 1s;

}
@keyframes clickit {
    from {display: none;}
    to {display: block}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="exec">
        <h2>
            execute portfolio;
        </h2>
    </div>
    <button class="enter">enter</button>
</body>
```

Comment: you cannot animate display, try `visibility`

Comment: @keyframes clickit {
    from {visibility: hidden;}
    to {visibility: visible;}
}
this doesn't restore its visibility after 1 second.

Comment: it does : https://jsfiddle.net/f7sb5yg4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just update your code with few **CSS**, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko);
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #3c3f41;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.exec h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:
        typing 1s steps(20, end),
        cursor 0.5s step-end infinite;
    /*animation-delay: 5s;*/
}
@keyframes typing {
    from{ width: 0 }
    to{ width: 100% }
}
@keyframes cursor{
    from, to {
        border-color: transparent;}
    50% {
        border-color: orange;
    }
}
.enter{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 15px;
    min-width: 70px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    animation: clickit 1.5s
}
@keyframes clickit {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    80% {opacity: 0}
    100% {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="exec">
        <h2>
            execute portfolio;
        </h2>
    </div>
    <button class="enter">enter</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Display does not work with CSS transitions or animations, check out this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607330/css-display-none-and-opacity-animation-with-keyframes-not-working) to understand it a bit better.

I suggest you transition the `opacity` or the `visibility` of the button instead of its display.

```
@keyframes clickit {
    from { opacity : 0 ; /* Or visibility: hidden; */ }
    to { opacity : 1; /* Or visibility: visible; */ }
}
```

Comment: Am I supposed to set opacity: 0; in ".enter" class before this?

Comment: okay yes, I had to and it works now. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Display property cant be animated.
And if you use `animation-delay:1s` then the button will still show for 1s before animations starts.
try below code.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko);
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #3c3f41;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.exec h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:
        typing 1s steps(20, end),
        cursor 0.5s step-end infinite;
    /*animation-delay: 5s;*/
}
@keyframes typing {
    from{ width: 0 }
    to{ width: 100% }
}
@keyframes cursor{
    from, to {
        border-color: transparent;}
    50% {
        border-color: orange;
    }
}
.enter{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 15px;
    min-width: 70px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: clickit 2s ease;
}
@keyframes clickit {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    50% {opacity:0;}
    1000% {opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="exec">
        <h2>
            execute portfolio;
        </h2>
    </div>
    <button class="enter">enter</button>
</body>
```