# Hamburger menu not working using CSS only

Tags: html, css, animation

I have the following code. The hamburger menu is always being displayed, irrespective whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked .hamburger-menu {
  animation: menu-display 0.3s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes menu-display {
  from {
    display: none;
  }
  to {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar-div-outside'>
  <nav class='navbar'>
    <div class='logo-div'>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class='navbar-brand'>DevByAnirudh</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-div'>
      {% block navbar %}{% endblock navbar %}
    </div>
    <div class='nav-icons'>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://www.instagram.com/devbyanirudh/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></p>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://twitter.com/devbyanirudh"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></p>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCefdYcnQIHbRhPp0N8UIQsw"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- hamburger menu part -->
    <div class='hamburger'>
      <label for="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-bars bars"></i></label>
      <input class='checkbox' type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
  <div class='hamburger-menu'>
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'BlogListView' %}">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `.hamburger-menu` to display when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I assume you want an animation effect as the hamburger comes into view. You can't use display as that is not animatable but you could use opacity so the hamburger appears more gradually. Is that suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your css selector `input[type=checkbox]:checked .hamburger-menu`.

That selector selects a element with the class `.hamburger-menu` inside a `input[type=checkbox]` element with the state `:checked`.

Your markup does not contain a such construct (which would be invalid anyways cause you literally can not put content inside a `<input/>` tag).

Anyways, even if it would select correctly, youre trying to animate the `display` css propery which [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607330/css-display-none-and-opacity-animation-with-keyframes-not-working).

Dropping that animation attempt, you could use JavaScript to show/hide the menu.

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
let menu = document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked === true)
    menu.classList.add('visible');
  else
    menu.classList.remove('visible');
});
```

```css
.hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-menu.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar-div-outside'>
  <nav class='navbar'>
    <div class='logo-div'>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class='navbar-brand'>DevByAnirudh</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-div'>
      {% block navbar %}{% endblock navbar %}
    </div>
    <div class='nav-icons'>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://www.instagram.com/devbyanirudh/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></p>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://twitter.com/devbyanirudh"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></p>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCefdYcnQIHbRhPp0N8UIQsw"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- hamburger menu part -->
    <div class='hamburger'>
      <label for="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-bars bars"></i></label>
      <input class='checkbox' type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
  <div class='hamburger-menu'>
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'BlogListView' %}">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, how do I select the class `hamburger-menu` when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: You _could_ use the css `~` selector but that would require reforming your html (@ANDO Andriamalala just added a solution using that). I'd recommend using javascript in combination with a visiblity class for your menu. By doing so you dont need to change your html at all. I added a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
input[type=checkbox] ~ .hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hamburger-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar-div-outside'>
  <nav class='navbar'>
    <div class='logo-div'>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class='navbar-brand'>DevByAnirudh</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-div'>
      {% block navbar %}{% endblock navbar %}
    </div>
    <div class='nav-icons'>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://www.instagram.com/devbyanirudh/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></p>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://twitter.com/devbyanirudh"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></p>
      <p><a target='_blank' href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCefdYcnQIHbRhPp0N8UIQsw"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- hamburger menu part -->
    <div class='hamburger'>
      <label for="checkbox"><i class="fas fa-bars bars"></i></label>
      <input class='checkbox' type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
      <div class='hamburger-menu'>
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'BlogListView' %}">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->
</div>
```