# CSS Transition delay in but not out

Tags: css, css-transitions

Using CSS I'm trying to get a transition delay to work as follows. I want a 1s delay in but I want 0s delay out.

```
transition: width 0.3s ease-in 1s;
transition: width 0.3s ease-out 0s;
```

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58jbuxL5/1/)

Comment: Like this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/58jbuxL5/2/)? Also to override `delay` you only need `transition-delay: 1s;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different CSS transition-delays for hover and mouseout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921073/different-css-transition-delays-for-hover-and-mouseout) -- only difference is the hover, but the basic answer is the same and the trigger event is not defined in this  question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have the delay under your `.active` block, since the element has the active class when it is transitioning to green:

```
.sample {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
.sample.active {
    background-color: green;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 1s;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/58jbuxL5/4/)

Answer (score 5):

slightly more concise and maintainable code, set the `transition-delay` property instead of rewriting the whole `transition`:

```
.sample {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
.sample.active {
    background-color: green;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58jbuxL5/7/)

documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
.sample {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.sample.active {
    background-color: green;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

You don't need an `!important` declaration because the cascade automatically prefers the later rule when you overwrite a property.

You also don't need to rewrite the entire transition rule since you specifically want to use the *same transition* with a *different delay* rather than a *different transition*.

The reason it's this way around (with the `0s` delay by default) is that when you remove the `.active` class you stop applying its colour as well as its transition delay so the delay in the `.sample` class is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**CSS**

```
.sample {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
.sample.active {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 1s !important;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 1s !important;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/58jbuxL5/6/)**